# Selecting input field to add value

Tags: jquery, forms, input, filter

The following script sets the value of a variable in a form field. However, I'm having trouble restricting the script to only writing to the intended form/field. The comments form is also being populated with the same value.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
   <?php $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>

   var pageAddress="<?php echo $url?>";

   $('#testform a').click( function (){
      $(":input[name$='feedbackform']").val(pageAddress);
   });
});
```

I tried refining the selector by adding the id of the target form thus:

```
$(" #formcontainter   :input[name$='feedbackform']").val(pageAddress);
```

but that doesn't stop the script writing to the fields in the commment form

What is the correct way to select the form and fields for the script to insert its value.

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML markup it's impossible to give an answer to this question.

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YDUwV/

Comment: Unless you have several fields with the same name (feedbackform) it should work.

Comment: @ Michael Mior: Fair comment. I was hoping that my syntax was so badly mangled that someone with more knowledge that I have would point to the error of my ways. This has a little complexity in that the form is loaded into a dialog on a Wordpress page.

Comment: @ Ryan Gross. Thanks for the feedback. Yes I should have gone to jsfiddle and done the test. Your confirmation gave me the solution to the problem. I guessed that the php variable was causing a problem, changed it and it now works. This code is on a Wordpress page and I don't know what WP/theme is doing with their form, and I was convinced that it was a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
$(" #formcontainter input[name$='feedbackform']").val(pageAddress);
```

or if the input is immediate child then

```
$(" #formcontainter > input[name$='feedbackform']").val(pageAddress);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Using the tag doesn't solve the problem. Is it incorrect to use that format with the jquery selector?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but here is what I would do. Open firebug in firefox, and run the command above. See what gives you results. Like one of the comments said, without js we can't really help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

     $('#a').click( function (){
         $(":input[name$='feedbackform']").val(pageAddress);
     });

});

<input name="a" id="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $url?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My apologies I was trying to keep things simple but the complication here is that the form is loaded as an html snippet and appears in a dialog. So I have to capture the url of the 'host' page and then pass it into the form after the form has loaded. I was unsuccessful at doing this with a php only solution. Note that the 'click' function in my sample is there to make sure that the pageAddress is loaded after the form is loaded.